# MVC5 application on GoDaddy plex server. All I get is '500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, godaddy-api

I have built an MVC5 application and moved it to my GoDaddy plex server. All I get is '500  An exception occurred while processing your request'. I was told by GoDaddy that I had to have an Index.aspx page to start the application. I do not belive this to be true else all MVC application would have to do this. It runs fine on my local pc. I have also set the trust=full in the config. Can anyone shed some light on this...very frustrating

Comment: Can you check your logs? Logs from your browser (if it even starts there), logs from your IDE, or even better, place a `try { } catch () { }` around the code and check what it says. Perhaps that'll help you solve the problem.

Comment: deploye your app in debug mode (customError=Off, compilation debug=true) so that you can see whats going on, you also need to set `<trust level="Full" />` in system.web section

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the default document in your web.config - as seen below.

```html
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />               
            <add value="Home/Index"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```